# How to test preventDefault in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, events, jasmine

I have this function:

```
preventLink() {
    const links = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.pfm-dropdown-base-menu a'));
    links.forEach(a => {
        a.addEventListener('click', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
}
```

I need to test it with jasmine. In the `beforeAll` I have this so far:

```
beforeAll(() => {
    const link = document.querySelector('.pfm-dropdown-popout ul li a');
});
```

"link" is what I need to simulate a click on, and test if `preventDefault()` is called.

But I cannot find a way to mock the event to spyOn.